# OnEditorActionListener not working on multiline EditText

Tags: java, android, input, editor

I have an activity which only contains a toolbar and an EditText.
I have been searching for a solution for a while now(a few days),but haven't found anything.
Here is my xml:

```
<AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/contentedittext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="start|top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />
```

I read that this problem should be solved after changing the input type to 'singleLine', but i need my EditText to be multiline.
In my java  code, i set an OnEditorActionListener to catch possible (soft keyboard) enter presses, but it is not being fired and that is m problem

#### Here's my java code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(Theme.getCurrentAppTheme(this));
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_vr);
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.editor_toolbar));

    res = getResources();
    edit_area = findViewById(R.id.contentedittext);
    edit_area.addTextChangedListener(editorWatcher);
    edit_area.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorActionListener);
    try {
        edit_area.setText(initFile().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG,e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
    }
}
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mEditorActionListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "editoraction");
    int pointerPos = edit_area.getSelectionStart();
    SpannableStringBuilder editable = new SpannableStringBuilder(edit_area.getText().toString());
    if (keEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "enter");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
   }};
```

Comment: Can you post java code?

Comment: @IshanFernando yes, added it.